# Get pixel data from Graphics object in Codename One

Tags: graphics, gaussian, codenameone

I'm trying to implement the Gaussian blur filter on Graphics object, but I can't find function for get pixel information or transform Graphics object to byte array (with RGB data).

Answer (score 1):

That isn't supported since hardware accelerated surfaces might not provide that information.

However, you can do something else. Just paint the current form onto a mutable image and then just get the RGB of the mutable image which you can then use to create a new `Image` from an RGB e.g. something close to this:

```
Display d = Display.getInstance();
Image img = Image.createImage(d.getDisplayWidth(), d.getDisplayHeight());
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
d.getCurrent().paintBackgrounds(g);
d.getCurrent().paintComponent(g, false);
int[] bufferArray = img.getRGB();

// blur...

Image blurredImage = Image.createImage(bufferArray, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
```

Comment: This function returns 0x000000 or 0xFFFFFF as pixels values

Comment: The values should be AARRGGBB values so FFFFFF == 0 technically. White would be ffffffff.

Comment: However, this is not the pixels of screen.

Comment: OK, I see. There was a bug in the code, I only painted the backgrounds and not the actual component.